# How to Caluculate data per year per employee

Tags: sql

I need to find a way to calculate total salary per employee per year

I have a list of employee's data which i need to sum their total salaries per each employee per year

below is sample data

[image: sample data]

Comment: You need to provide some sample data, so people can come up with a reproducible examples.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free coding service. You need to provide some sample data and queries you've tried before *in the body of your question*, as well as where your previous attempts have fallen flat. Additionally, you should tag the specific RDBMS engine you're leveraging as answers could vary substantially from one to the next. For starters: `SELECT SUM(SALARY) / COUNT(EMPLOYEE) FROM data GROUP BY YEAR`

Answer (score 0):

This is basic use of SQL that would be covered in any class, book, or online course.  In general you should not ask these "how do you code it" questions on this site but instead ask questions about code you have already written, we are not here to write it for you we are here to help if you have problems.  On the other hand it is easy:

```
select employee_no, year, sum(sal_amount)
from table_name_you_did_no_say
group by emplyee_no, year
```

Answer (score -1):

You could make yourself a formula like this:

```
salary_per_annum = salary_per_month * 12
```

What you really need to do is to first categorize your staff based on the salary they earn.
If they earn allowances/bonuses, you could make a different calculations for that too and then add the both values.

If you're talking of an SQL query, for each employee, you could loop:

```
select sum(salary) * 12
```

If you're looking to calculate and group, you could have:

```
select employee_num, sal_year, salary from tbl_payrol group by emplyee_num, sal_amount
```

Comment: using `select *` and `group by` is a terrible idea.